# Macro doesn't work when copied into another workbook

Tags: excel, module, vba

I had to make an exact copy of a workbook in order to translate it, and the macros do not work because its source is the original workbook (according to the debugger). How can I make these macros work in the new workbook? can I change the macro code in the new workbook?

Comment: Please post your code.  Without it, it's hard to say what could be causing it, it could be many different things.  Likely, it's making explicit references to sheets/macros that aren't in your new one.

Comment: Sub Client()
'
' Client Macro
'

'
    
    Range("Table28[#All]").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange _
        :=Range("Table26[[#All],[Corto Plazo]]"), Unique:=False
    
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
     
    Range("B3").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("B3").Select
    
    Workbooks.Open ("F:\Advisory\AAA Ficheros de Propuesta\Master Files\Propuesta Integral - Master File\Datos de Cliente\Positions.xlsm")

Comment: Sheets("E.SC.POS.ASSET.BS").Select
    Range("F1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AX$60123").AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:= _
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C2"), Operator:=xlAnd
    Range("AY1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Propuesta Global - Template (Nuevo Formato).xlsm").Activate
    Range("B3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Comment: Can you please edit that into your OP, and mark with the code tags (`{}`)? It's hard to read via comments.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the macro and how it is programmed.
If the macro use absolute paths like the place where the file is locate you need to change the macro.

You can programm macro in different styles. To use it for different workbooks you can programm it with the ActiveWorkbook object. So if you open a workbook and start it, it will use the active one. You can even use it when you open the file with the macro and then change to a other workbook, because then that workbook is the active one.

You need to look at the macro how it is programmed. Like you said, if you close all workbooks, copy the file, start the new file and it still reference the old one then there should be a absolute path in the macro code.

Open the macro with the macroeditor and look for something like this:

```
Dim WB As Workbook
```

WB is an Variable here so it can be any other name, too. For the example I go here with the WB. When you found the workbook variable look for some like this:

```
Set WB = Workbooks.Open("c:\somewhere\file.xlsm")
```

There you need to place the path with the new location or change it to

```
Set WB = ActiveWorkbook
```

or

```
Set WB = ThisWorkbook
```

The different between this two is just that ActiveWorkbook always use the active one, so can use it for more then one workbook without the need to import it to the new file . If you choose ThisWorkbook the marco will always reference the Workbook with the macro belongs, too.

I hope that is what you needed.

**EDIT**
After reading the unformated code, there you go:

```
    Workbooks.Open ("F:\Advisory\AAA Ficheros de Propuesta\Master Files\Propuesta Integral - Master File\Datos de Cliente\Positions.xlsm")
```

That might be the problem